# Xamarin Dynamic File Paths, Deleting and Creating files

Tags: c#, android, file, xamarin, filesystems

I am making my first and last Xamarin Android app, and all i need to do is overwrite a file. No buttons, no nothing.
It is located in a folder inside the com.applicationwhatever folders. How can i get that path?

On my android device the path is /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.xxx.xxx/files [Es File explorer]
Can i just use that in my file stream? If so, i fear that the path to the com.xxx.xxx folder will change with other devices. How can i get the equivalent of an environment variable to the /data folder? Then, i can access the file and overwrite it.
Also, do i need to do something else to be able to delete and create a file? I am thinking about using the File class, but i don't know anything about android permisions.
How can i make my app acces the folder and overwrite the file?

Comment: so the /data/user/0/ applies on any device. That was unclear to me. Thank you.

Comment: `so the /data/user/0/ applies on any device. ` No. Wrong conclusion.

Comment: it does not work. I get an access denied error (while debugging on my device with Enable USB debugging). I have also checked read and write permissions in the props. The path must be incorrect.

Comment: Can you please tell me which environment variable will get me to the Android/data folder?

Comment: There are 3 special folders : Application Data, Common Application Data and Local Application Data. Which one applies here?

Comment: @Jason NO, i am overwriting another app's files.

Comment: @Jason well, how can my file explorer do that?

Comment: The file is not protected in any way. It is just some data.

Comment: @Jason I have solved the issue. Your argument was and is flawed.

Answer (score 0):

To get permissions, i just did the following :

```
 while (ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage) != (int)Permission.Granted)
 {
     RequestPermissions(new string[] { Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage, Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage, Manifest.Permission.Internet }, 0);
 }
```

Then i just hardcoded the path. It apparently works on all devices i tested it on (with different versions of android).

```
var path = "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.xxx/data/file";
```